# Is there a way to get pg_dump to exclude a specific sequence?

Tags: postgresql, sequences, pg-dump

I want to exclude a sequence from my pg_dump command which is putting the output into a plain file.

```
Command: /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_dump --host localhost --port 5433 --username xxx --format plain --clean --inserts --verbose --file /Users/xxx/documents/output/SYSTEM_admin_20131126015325.sql --exclude-table public.table1 --exclude-table public.table2 mydatabase
```

I know there are switches for tables which i am using above and that you can enable/disable database objects in the tar format in combination with pg_restore as stated in the [pg_dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgdump.html) but I will not be using pg_restore.

Many Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. The sequence to exclude is **owned by a table** you're also dumping (typical case: `SERIAL` column).
   See: [Dump a table without sequence table in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141518/dump-a-table-without-sequence-table-in-postgres)
   Short answer: no, the sequence can't be left aside.
2. The sequence is **not owned** by a dumped table. Then it can be excluded with the `--exclude-table` switch as if it was a table.

From pg_dump documentation:

> -T table
>   --exclude-table=table
>
> ```
> Do not dump any tables matching the table pattern.
> ```
>
> The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for -t

And about `-t`:

> -t table
>   --table=table
>
> ```
> Dump only tables (or views or sequences or foreign tables) matching table
> ```

Comment: It is a sequence that is not owned by the table, so the exclude-table option works great.

Comment: `-T table` statement is **very important**. Do not let your intuitions fool you on that part. By CLI arguments standards, you would think that the `-T table` is no longer needed since it was already stated in the `--exclude-table=table`. It would seem argument-redundant but it is really needed for a successful exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence is owned by a table you can exclude both the sequence and the table using -T, such as:

```
pg_dump -T table -T table_id_seq
```

Comment: Wouldn't it exclude both sequence AND the table from dump?

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy yes